# What does “/EndEntire” followed by “file path: /ACPI(…,…)/PCI(…)/UnknownMessaging(…)/HD(…,…,…,…,…)/File(…)/File(…)/EndEntire” during boot mean?

Tags: multi-boot, grub, windows-11, grub2, secure-boot

I use Secure Boot, followed by GRUB2, set up to boot Debian 12 and Windows 11 at the choice of a user. Right after the user chooses Windows and hits ⏎, we see a black screen with two white lines on it (the text may be slightly screwed due to retyping from bad screenshots) in the left upper corner:

```
/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(a0341d0,0)/PCI(4,1d)/PCI(0,0)/UnknownMessaging(17)/HD(1,800,82000,bc49b1f82df92a47,2,2)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot)/File(bootmgfw.sfi)/EndEntire
```

The screen contains no further output.

BIOS/UEFI, GRUB when booting Linux, and Windows are not known to be too talkative during boot in modern days in general. So, I guess, the user better pays attention to the above message. Which piece of software issues this message? What does the message tell us?